# Custom post pagination not working

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination, homepage, custom-post-type-archives

I have a big problem with my custom post pagination on home.php page. It shows the first 4 post but when I go to the second page I get a page with only the header and footer but no news content and no sidebar.

In the chrome console I get an error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Below is my code. I'm creating a theme from scratch. It looks like wordpress would loose the content.php on second page or some other file. What could be the problem?

function.php

```
function pagination($pages = '', $range = 4)
{
 $showitems = ($range * 2)+1;

 global $paged;
 if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;

 if($pages == '')
 {
     global $wp_query;
     $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
     if(!$pages)
     {
         $pages = 1;
     }
 }

 if(1 != $pages)
 {
     if($paged > 2 && $paged > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link(1)."'>&laquo; First</a>";
     if($paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged - 1)."'>&lsaquo; Previous</a>";

     for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++)
     {
         if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems ))
         {
             echo ($paged == $i)? "<span class=\"current\">".$i."</span>":"<a href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."' class=\"inactive\">".$i."</a>";
         }
     }

     if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href=\"".get_pagenum_link($paged + 1)."\">Next &rsaquo;</a>";
     if ($paged < $pages-1 &&  $paged+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($pages)."'>Last &raquo;</a>";
     echo "</div>\n";
 }
}
```

home.php

```
<div class="main-content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar col-xl-4">
      <?php get_template_part( 'templates/sidebar' ); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="news-content col-xl-8">
      <h1>News</h1>

      <?php
        $paged = ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'page' ) : 1;

        $args = array(
          'post_type'      => 'news',
          'posts_per_page' => 4,
          'paged'          => $paged
        );

        $custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );

        while($custom_query->have_posts()) :
          $custom_query->the_post();
      ?>

      <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) :?>

        <div class="news-wrapper col-xl-6">
          <div class="news-date">
            <?php the_time('j.m.Y'); ?>
          </div><!-- .news-date -->
          <div class="news-img">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
          </div><!-- .news-img -->
          <a class="news-title" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
          </a><!-- .news-title -->
          <div class="news-text">
            <?php echo short_excerpt(25); ?>
          </div>
          <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="btn">
            read more
          </a><!-- .btn -->
        </div><!-- .news-wrapper -->

       <?php else :?>

        <div class="news-wrapper col-xl-6">
          <div class="news-date">
            <?php the_time('j.m.Y'); ?>
          </div><!-- .news-date -->
          <a class="news-title" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
          </a><!-- .news-title -->
          <div class="news-text">
            <?php echo short_news_content(70); ?>
          </div>
          <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="btn">
           read more
          </a><!-- .btn -->
        </div><!-- .news-wrapper -->

      <?php
        endif;
        endwhile;
      ?>
      <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
      <nav class="pagination col-xl-12">
        <?php if (function_exists("pagination")) {pagination($custom_query->max_num_pages);} ?>
      </nav>
    </div><!-- .news-content -->
  </div><!-- .container -->
</div><!-- .main-content -->
```

### **EDIT**

I was digging for the reason why the pagination is giving a 404 error. I have deleted my home.php file for now and I was left with the index.php witch is showing only the header and footer. And this is exactly what I see on my CPTs second page. I have added later on the else `no posts` to check my suspicions.

```
  <?php
  if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

  endwhile;
else:
   echo '<p>no post</p>';
  endif;
?>
```

so for some reason on the index page wordpress is not able to show my CPT. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: for static home page use `page` instead of `paged`. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: I have updated my query at home.php but still got this problem.

Comment: try nav tag before wp_reset_query and  after endwhile

Comment: I moved the nav tag as you suggested but it didn't work

Comment: You can't paginate a custom query beyond the number of pages in the main query on any kind of archive page. Use `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query rather than create a custom query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Milo's comment I could find a solution.

In my home.php I have deleted the custom query and inserted:

```
<div class="news-content col-12 col-xl-8">
      <div class="row">
        <h1>News</h1>
      </div><!-- .row -->

      <div class="row">
          <?php

            if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

              if(has_post_thumbnail()) :?>

                <div class="news-wrapper col-12 col-xl-6">
                  <div class="news-date">
                    <?php the_time('j.m.Y'); ?>
                  </div><!-- .news-date -->
                  <div class="news-img">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                  </div><!-- .news-img -->
                  <a class="news-title" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                  </a><!-- .news-title -->
                  <div class="news-text">
                    <?php echo short_excerpt(25); ?>
                  </div>
                  <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="btn">
                    czytaj dalej
                  </a><!-- .btn -->
                </div><!-- .news-wrapper -->

              <?php else :?>

                <div class="news-wrapper col-12 col-xl-6">
                  <div class="news-date">
                    <?php the_time('j.m.Y'); ?>
                  </div><!-- .news-date -->
                  <a class="news-title" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                  </a><!-- .news-title -->
                  <div class="news-text">
                    <?php echo short_news_content(70); ?>
                  </div>
                  <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="btn">
                    czytaj dalej
                  </a><!-- .btn -->
                </div><!-- .news-wrapper -->

              <?php
                endif;
                endwhile;
                endif;
              ?>
      </div><!-- .row -->
      <div class="row">
        <?php the_posts_pagination( array( 'mid_size'  => 2 ) ); ?>
      </div>
    </div><!-- .news-content -->
  </div><!-- .container -->
</div><!-- .main-content -->
```

and in my functions.php file I have added:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_post_on_homepage' );

function custom_post_on_homepage( $query ) {

 if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )
  {
    $query->set('post_type', 'news');
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '4' );
  }
 }
```

Hope this helps someone in the future.